# Discrete probability question on sample space

Tags: probability

I'm trying to determine the sample space for the following [problem 8](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_5_solved3.php).  Appreciate if anyone can help me understand what it looks like.

"A family has two children. We choose one of them at random and find out that she is a girl. What is the probability that both children are girls?"

There are four possibilities:

$GC=(\text{girl},\text{girl}), GB, BG, BB$.  $P(GG) = P(GB) = P(BG) = P(BB) = \frac14$.

Let $G_r$ be the event that a randomly chosen child is a girl.  Then we have:

$$P(G_r\mid GG) = 1$$

$$P(G_r\mid GB) = P(G_r\mid BG) = \frac12$$

$$P(G_r\mid BB) = 0$$

This is the beginning of the problem where I'm trying to determine the sample space.  Specifically for the following equation:

$$P(G_r\mid GB) = P(G_r \cap GB)/P(GB) = \frac12$$

From this, I know that $P(G_r \cap GB)$ should be $1/8$, however am unable to figure out the events and sample space leading to such an answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by $P(B)$.  In any case:  The probability that the oldest child is a girl and the youngest a boy is $\frac 14$. In that situation, the probability that you select the girl is $\frac 12$, so the probability of the intersection is $\frac 14\times \frac 12=\frac 18$.

Comment: I fixed $P(B)$ to be $P(GB)$.  How are you multiplying these probabilities when $P(G_r \cap GB)$ is the probability of the intersection of the events?

Comment: That's not good notation. The sample space here consists of triples, where the first slot is the gender of the eldest child, the second slot is the gender of the youngest child, and the third slot tells you whether you selected eldest or youngest. Each triple is equiprobable and there are $8$ triples.

Comment: @lulu There is no eldest or youngest involved in this problem.

Comment: You have distinguished $GB$ from $BG$.  How?  In my sample space I distinguish them by age.  You don't have to do it that way, but you have distinguished them somehow. You could design a sample space in which you don't distinguish them at all but in that case your events are not equiprobable.  The probability of having mixed genders would be twice the probability of two girls, say.

Comment: This same "ambiguity" arises constantly.  If you are tossing a pair of dice, say, it is often a good idea to distinguish the two dice, even if that feels arbitrary.  Doing so makes every roll equiprobable.   But you can also choose not to distinguish them.  Nothing wrong with that, but then the probability of tossing a $1$ and a $6$ is twice the probability of throwing two $1's$.

Comment: @lulu I was thinking that the ordered pair $p \in \{G,B\} \times \{G, B\}$ would distinguish them by order.

Comment: Well, what does that mean in practice?  Simply that each child is designated First or Second?  Sure, if you want.  I think it is more natural to distinguish them by age, but it's fine if you want to simply assign the labels First and Second (so long as your method for assigning labels is independent of gender).

Comment: @lulu My main question is how $P(G_r|GB) = P(GB \cap G_r)/P(GB) = 1/2$, where $P(GB \cap G_r) = 1/8$.  I keep coming back to the question what $GB \cap G_r$ would look like in order to result in an elementary event that $=1/8$.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: I've given you a clear method!  There are $8$ equiprobable events.  Using your "First, Second" designation we have $(G,G, First), (G, G, Second), (G,B, First), (G,B, Second), (B,G, First),$$ (B,G, Second), (B,B, First), (B,B, Second)$.  Your event $G_r\cap GB$ is precisely the event $(G,B, First)$.

Comment: @lulu that makes sense thanks!  The third element of the triple specifies the randomly chosen child.  $G_r = \{(G,G,First), (G,G,Second),(G,B,First),(B,G,Second)\}$.  $BG = \{(B,G,First),(B,G,Second)\}$.  Like you say $G_r \cap BG = \{(B,G,Second)\}$.  Where $P(\{(B,G,Second)\}) = 1/8$.

Comment: @lulu I keep encountering probability problems like this, even in texts, that do not specify the sample space or events clearly.  Should I be concerned with this?

Comment: Well, it's standard (I think) for people to try to avoid writing out sample spaces explicitly.  In this problem it was easy to write it all out, but it's easy to come up with simple situations in which it is truly unpleasant to try to write it all down.  It's certainly not a bad exercise to try to add the details that your text treats casually.